# Use of % sign before a function name in scilab?

Tags: scilab

Can anyone help me to understand this code of Scilab?
Assume flag = 'c', thres = 2 and A be some matrix.

```
deff("[flag]=%smallei(x)","flag=real(x) >= thres")
[X,dsmall] = schur(A,%smallei);
```

Though, I get that 'deff' is being used to make a function named %smallei and it is comparing the values. But in Schur function, %smallei is used without input parameters. Please help me, what this code snippet is doing and where I'm wrong.

For complete Scilab code - http://cgit.scilab.org/scilab/plain/scilab/modules/linear_algebra/macros/psmall.sci?h=5.1&id=b97dd3f34da8b52ac799da43848d8d0910d83aef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *schur* function internally calls the *%smallei* function, as you are passing a pointer to the function in *schur* (see the [help](https://help.scilab.org/doc/5.5.2/en_US/schur.html)). The *schur* function calls this function pointer by passing him an argument ('x' in your example) and expecting to return one value ('flag' in your example). Therefore, you can make *schur* working with any function that follows the *%smallei* prototype.

This is a typical approach in optimization algorithms, in which you have a general algorithm that could be used with different optimization criteria. So, you split your algorithm between the general code and a specific function used for the criteria, and this function is called in the algorithm as a function pointer. The user could decide which define custom criteria to use by injecting the optimization function as a function pointer.

Comment: Is it also possible to pass variables by reference to a Scilab function as I have asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55060752/how-pass-variables-by-reference-to-a-scilab-function). I would appreciate if you could help me with the question.