# How pass variables by reference to a Scilab function

Tags: function, pointers, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, scilab

I want to have a Scilab function which is able to alter its input variables, For example in `C` I could have

```
void double(int* x){
    *x *= 2;
    return;
}
```

There are `intppty`, `funptr`, `addinter`, `istk`, `sadr` and `stk` in Scilab which seem to be relevant, however I can't find any working example. Scilab does have a `pointer` type (i.e. `128`).  I would appreciate if you could help me figure this out.

**P.S.1.** I have also mirrored this question [here on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/ayolbx/how_pass_variables_by_reference_to_a_scilab/).

**P.S.2.** Scilab also have `intersci`, `SWIG`, `fort`, `external`, `call`, `API_Scilab`/`gateway` which can interface `C`/`C++` functions or `Fortran` subroutines. Unfortunately `intersci` has been deprecated and `SWIG` seems to be only for Linux with limited `C++` compatibility.

**P.S.3.** scilab has [function overloading](https://help.scilab.org/doc/5.5.2/en_US/overloading.html) which can do stuff with the functions defined by `deff` and a combination of `%`,`<...>`,`_...` syntax.

**P.S.4.** The way `API_Scilab`/`gateway` works, is basically you dvelop the code using functionalities provided bu the header file `api_scilab.h`, compile it with `ilib_build`, write a `loader*.sce` script and then load it with `exec`.

**P.S.5.** supposedly one should be able to install `mingw` compiler with

```
atomsInstall('mingw'); atomsLoad('mingw');
```

However I am not able to get it to work as  I have explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55063203/atomsinstall-cant-find-the-mingw-compiler-installed-through-chocolatey).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible by using, e.g. a C++ Scilab 6 gateway (example needs a compiler on the machine, it should not be a problem for Linux and OSX users):

```
gw=[
"#include ""double.hxx"""
"#include ""function.hxx"""
"types::Function::ReturnValue sci_incr(types::typed_list &in, int _iRetCount,"
"                                      types::typed_list &out)"
"{"    
"    if (in.size() != 1 || in[0]->isDouble() == false) {"
"        throw ast::InternalError(""Wrong type/number of input argument(s)"");"
"    }"
"    types::Double *pDbl = in[0]->getAs<types::Double>();"
"    double *pdbl = pDbl->get();"
""    
"    for (int i=0; i < pDbl->getSize(); i++) (*pdbl) += 1.0;"
""
"    return types::Function::OK;"
"}"];
cd TMPDIR;
mputl(gw,TMPDIR+"/sci_incr.cpp");
ulink
ilib_build("incr", ["incr" "sci_incr" "cppsci"],"sci_incr.cpp", [])
exec loader.sce
```

After compilation/link of the interface, you can have the following behavior:

```
--> x=1
 x  = 

   1.

--> incr(x)

--> x
 x  = 

   2.
```

However, don't consider this as a feature, because the Scilab language has not been designed to use it !

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Have opened a [new bug report](http://bugzilla.scilab.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16025) hoping to solve [the compiler issue on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55063203/atomsinstall-cant-find-the-mingw-compiler-installed-through-chocolatey). Some questions: 1. I suppose C is also a possibility, isn't it? I do C but C++ is weird and confusing to me. 2. is it possible to have the C/C++ file separately? I guess I can read the file and then tokenize it with EOL? Is it possible to overload an existing Scilab function to accept by reference?

Comment: Answer to 1.: Yes, you have plenty of examples in Scilab Help (see e.g. `ilib_build`help page). But you should learn C++ if you want to contribute to Scilab internals. All new gateways are coded that way now. Answer to 2.: the cpp source file is [here](http://www.utc.fr/~mottelet/scilab/download/stackoverflow.com/sci_incr.cpp). By ref with overloading : no

Comment: Thanks again. some more questions: 1. What is "Equation Solution" which Samuel is referring to [here](http://bugzilla.scilab.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16025) and is also mentioned in the [MinGW ATOMS](https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/mingw/0.10.5)? is it an ATOMS? Would you be kind to help me with a link or instructions how it should be installed? 2. Is it possible to just link a function to an already compiled / built excusable or object or dll file?

Comment: See my answer to your post about MinGW.

Comment: Is it also possible to use other interfacing languages for this purpose? For example PowerShell or Tcl? Although they are slower, they do not require a compiler.

Comment: To me, passing arguments by reference is needed only in some very specific situations, e.g. when you absolutely need to avoid the memory overhead of statements like `A=A+B` when `A`and `B`are huge matrices. Here we would just need a `+=`operator. [Julia](https://julialang.org/) has such features that, if they appear to be necessary,  would have to be developed natively and not by using a pivot language.

Comment: well, you are right. that's one of the main applications, but the reason I need this passing by reference because I need to go around the lack of OOP in Scilab. For example for the Serial Port Toolbox, I need to have something like a set function to change the parameters of the serial struct. one way would be to use the whos output, the other question you answered, but that's extremely slow and inefficient. The other way would be to pass the serial struct by reference. Given that I'm using PS and Tcl for the Toolbox at the moment and they both seem to have OOP and pointers...

Answer (score 0):

For my understanding this is not possible, in scilab input arguments are in the right side of the function and outputs are on the left side. See https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.2/en_US/function.html

```
[output,...] = function(input,...)
```

So, if you would like an input/output argument you have to assign the input argument to the output one inside your function.

```
[c] = f1(a, b)
     c = a + b    
endfunction
```

And you call it using same variable as input and output argument:

```
d = 10;
d = f1(d, 1);
```