# atomsInstall can't find the mingw compiler installed through chocolatey

Tags: windows, mingw, scilab

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55060752/how-pass-variables-by-reference-to-a-scilab-function), I'm not quite sure where the problem is so I add tags for all the components involved. I'm trying to use the MinGw compiler inside Scilab. There is a mingw atom which supposedly should be installed by

```
atomsInstall('mingw')
```

which returns empty and

```
atomsLoad('mingw');
```

which returns the error:

> Mingw Compiler support for Scilab
>
> Load macros
>
> WARNING: MinGW Compiler not detected.
>
> Load help

and the `haveacompiler()` returns false `F`, although I have the compiler installed through Chocolatey. What could be the problem:

1. the compiler needs to be added to Windows environment variables or something like that? I suppose Chocolatey should take care of that by default. I have reflected this issue [here](https://chocolatey.org/packages/mingw#comment-4369441636) on mingw chocolatey page.
2. there is a bug in the mingw Scilab atom. I have contacted the maintainers Antoine Elias  and Allan Cornet for that possibility.
3. It is a mingw bug as some have sugested. I have shared this issue also [here](https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/lists/archive/users/2019-March/000253.html) on the mingw mailing list.

**P.S.1.** I have reported a bug over [here](http://bugzilla.scilab.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16025).

**P.S.2.** I have opened a new feature request over [here](https://bugzilla.scilab.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16030).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:** Tested on Scilab 6.0.1, Windows 7

1. first of all, download the Equation Solution compiler `gcc-6.2.0` package [32](http://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/mingw/0.10.0/files/gcc-6.2.0-32.exe) or [64](http://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/mingw/0.10.0/files/gcc-6.2.0-64.exe)
2. install it. It will just copy `gcc` and related `binuntils` in `C:/Users/yourUserId`.
3. Then start Scilab and install the MinGW Atoms module.
4. Then **logout/login your Windows session**. Restart Scilab. When loading, MinGW module takes some time (maybe some compilations), but does not complain.
5. Then the dynamic link example of `ilib_for_link` runs fine !

[image]

**Explanations:** The [Equation Solution package](http://www.equation.com/servlet/equation.cmd?fa=fortran) was developed by [Jenn-Ching Luo](https://www.researchgate.net/scientific-contributions/72544504_Jenn-Ching_Luo), the MinGW Atoms package was developed over this particular distribution of MinGW.

Comment: All other examples of  `ilib_build` help page work also fine (C,C++,Fortran). There is no bug in MinGW module, you just have to follow the instructions like I did.

Comment: thanks a lot Stéphane. Here some questions: 1. what is [this](http://www.equation.com/servlet/equation.cmd?fa=fortran) and how is it different from MinGW? is it just an interface to MinGW or it will overwrite my existing installation? Whi sis thew developer of this project? do they have forum issue tracking or an online repository to look into the source code? 2. why did you install 6.3 and not the latest 8.3? 3. link to this is not on the [mingw atoms page](https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/mingw).

Comment: Take time to read all the stuff on the MinGW page in Atoms manager **within Scilab** (not on atoms.scilab.org). In Scilab 6.0 there is a direct link go `gcc-6.2.0.exe`(hosted in Atoms site). So choosing `gcc-6.3.0` will not harm. In Scilab 5.5.2 there is in addition a link to `www.equation.com`. MinGW is made of open source software, it is natural that many different distributions exist.

Comment: This is indeed a very strange package, see the email I just forwarded to you. I'm going to try this inside a virtualbox to be sure it will not mess up my operating system. Also I'm not sure what you mean by "Atoms manager within Scilab". [Here](https://i.imgur.com/dzzbL7q.png) is what I see inside the Module manager.

Comment: OK I just relied that two links  [this](http://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/mingw/0.10.0/files/gcc-6.2.0-32.exe) and [this](http://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/mingw/0.10.0/files/gcc-6.2.0-64.exe)  are the ones you are referring to. They are also available on [the ATOMS page](https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/mingw). I had the wrong assumption that those are the links to the MinGW ATOMS binary in the case someone doesn't want to install through module manager or the `atomsInstall` command.

Comment: FYI it just copy gcc and related `binuntils` in `C:/Users/yourUserId`. I find your remarks and claims very rude considering the lack of resources we have for Scilab. MinGW Atoms package was developed over this particular distribution of MinGW, period. It's not always possible to be compliant with every different local choice of tools/distributions.

Comment: Dear Stéphane I'm sorry if any of my comments has bothered you. Would you be kind to help me know which comments and remarks are you referring to?

Comment: FYI Allan Cornet has sent me [this webpage](https://nelson-numerical-software.github.io/nelson-website/EXTERNAL_MODULE.html).

Comment: Nothing particular. Just always keep in mind that we contributors are just *contributors* and are not responsible of the *mess*  in Scilab which is highlighted  by your legitimate demands.

Comment: Dear Stéphane, Again I apologize for any rude comments. I assure you that I know how hard it is for your to maintain FOSS and offer these services with no expectation. I am aware that you guys do this just for the love you have for Free software and the appreciation of helping others. My only intention of all those criticisms is to improve thing not undermine your hard work. I hope my humble contributions will also be a little bit of help to improve the community. With love from UT 

Comment: I've recently followed this procedure on Windows 7 / Scilab 6.1.1
Unfortunately, even if the compiler is detected, the makefile pitifully try a del command and crashes. Looks nothing is designed at all for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Currently under Windows 7-64, scilab 6.1.1.

- the mentioned gcc is installed under C:/Users/myUserId.
- But, it miserably fails...

---

Converting Libraries.
Build libblasplus.a
atomsLoad : Une erreur est survenue au cours du chargement de 'mingw-9.2.0':
exec: error on line #64: "dos : Dimension erronée de l'argument d'entrée n°1 : Une chaîne de caractères attendue."

Comment: gcc is running in the environment:
-----------
C:\>gcc --version

gcc (GCC) 6.2.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: You have two different versions of MinGW (9.2.0 and 6.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue with "WARNING: MinGW Compiler not detected."

After successful installation of GCC compiler and MinGW Atoms Module I still got the problem.

My solution was to check and set the environmental variable EQ_LIBRARY_PATH properly:
EQ_LIBRARY_PATH=c:\program files\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib
(Open CMD and type "set")